# Using GSuite without hosted email, how to send messages using gscript MailApp

Tags: email, google-apps-script, outlook, automation, google-workspace

I am working on a project for a small company that is using both Office 365 and GSuite. They use Office 365 to host the domain, and to provide the mail backend. On GSuite they have a bunch of forms that we create, format into HTML pdf attachments and send to various clients. The company does not use GSuite/GMail for email.

Our initial tests of this system used a standalone gmail account, which obviously had @gmail.com address - and gscript MailApp worked just fine pumping out forms to the various clients seamlessly.

Migrating to GSuite (largely for HIPAA compliance) our forms processing account with all the form trigger events and code has an email like "formbot@company.com". When the form trigger fires, the MailApp sends the message coming from "formbot@company.com" - this works for any recipients with a gmail address, however most email servers generate some sort of error like:

550 XM-RJCT16: SPF Failure (ip=209.185.22.61, frm=formbot@company.com, result=fail)

Which makes sense, I guess...the message is not really coming from the right place.

So the question I have is, how do I send these messages via Outlook 365 from the gscript? I looked in the gsuite marketplace and didn't see anything. I also looked at some older messages he on SO, but the one thing I found didn't support attachments. I have to also admit, I'm doing this part time and pro bono - I am a graphics and game programmer by trade, so I can easily get in over my head.

My other thought was this - it seems like this gsuite account can send to gmail addresses just fine. Perhaps I could gscript MailApp the attachments to a regular gmail account and they in that account setup a trigger to reformat and send the email properly. Kind of a hack, but I guess it could work. I should note that the emails themselves are stripped of all patient identifying information, so it seems okay to relay them through a non HIPAA compliant account.

Anyway, thanks in advance for any suggestions or advice,
0xf00d

Comment: Can you share a sanitized version of the Apps Script code you are using to send the emails? And have you tried with [GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app) instead of MailApp?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add in your domain SPF the google IP address adding "include:_spf.google.com"

More info at https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=en